# How to find what's dumping to syslog?

Tags: networking, iptables, ufw, logging, syslog

The `/var/log/syslog` file (Ubuntu 16.04LTS) is currently expanding rapidly, and when I check the log contents, it is entirely filled with:

```
Dec  5 17:49:40 Desktop1 kernel: [54948.301365] IN=wlo1 OUT= MAC=xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx SRC=xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx DST=xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx LEN=88 TOS=0x10 PREC=0x00 TTL=64 ID=33465 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=59882 DPT=22 WINDOW=4096 RES=0x00 ACK PSH URGP=0
```

Without exception.

I understand that the Linux `syslog` file is a general dumping ground for process network events, however I do not recall ever experiencing `syslog` saturation on this scale and network activity for me is normal.

I have been messing around with Iptables and UFW rulesets, and it is possible that I somehow inadvertently enhanced logging. Regardless, the network events are listed as `Kernel`, and grants no insight into which process is responsible.

It is possible that I am just clueless and this is entirely normal, but just in case:

**My Questions:**

**- Is network IO logging on this scale normal?**

If not: Then I assume that simply restoring `iptables` and `UFW` rulesets should provide a quick fix:

**- How do I find iptables rule files and restore them?**

**- How do I find UFW rule files and restore them?**

(Ubuntu 16.04 LTS)

Comment: Do you have port forwarding on your router for port 22 to your machine? Because something hits your SSH port (i.e. DPT=22; destination port = 22) and SRC tells you from where the request came from and DST is where this request goes to.

Comment: "and grants no insight into which process is responsible." wlo1 is a hint too.  ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ufw` is a front-end for iptables, so we only need address ufw. Please see: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/UncomplicatedFirewall Is your syslog filled up to kilobyte levels or megabytes or even larger? Find out:

```
ls -al /var/log/syslog*
ls -al /var/log/ufw*
```

You can restore ufw to defaults with:

```
sudo ufw reset
```

This command also disables ufw, so if you want it restarted at default levels, then do:

```
sudo ufw enable
```

You can adjust the logging level with:

```
sudo ufw logging LEVEL
```

Where LEVEL may be 'off', 'low', 'medium', 'high' and 'full'. ufw defaults to 'low'.

Reference: `man ufw`

Comment: I understand that UFW is a front-end for iptables, but what does this mean in the context of the rules? Are all iptables rules managed by UFW or do they remain separate?

Comment: All iptables rules are managed by ufw. They are not separate.